# how do you create highstock multi line chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to createa multi line highstock type of chart:

My test.json file looks like this:

```
[{"name":"serverA","data":[[1372737609,2.6075],[1372737906,2.6533],[1372738205,2.7834],[1372738526,3.6527],[1372738802,0.6352],[1372739093,0.6073]]},{"name":"serverB","data":[[1372737602,36.3042],[1372737929,16.1145],[1372738218,6.4503],[1372738503,23.8908],[1372738803,3.9025],[1372739079,10.8216],[1372739371,3.1338]]},{"name":"serverC","data":[[1372737600,3.9025],[1372737908,13.8542],[1372738184,10.9094],[1372738491,14.6655],[1372738777,80.7615],[1372739081,6.9777],[1372739383,10.0971]]}]
```

This is my script:

```
(function() {
    var seriesOptions = [],
        yAxisOptions = [],

        colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;



        $.getJSON('test.txt',   function(data) {
            alert(data);
            seriesOptions: data
            createChart();      
        });

    // create the chart when all data is loaded
    function createChart() {

        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 4
            },

            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                    }
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 2,
                    color: 'silver'
                }]
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    compare: 'percent'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                valueDecimals: 2
            },

            series: seriesOptions
        });
    }

});
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from: `seriesOptions: data` to `seriesOptions = data;`

Comment: I did your recommendation, there still not chart. Were you able to create the chart given the above data?

Comment: Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/277/ Two more things, which may be the problem: make sure you have downloaded Highstock now Highcharts, and you are creating chart after all is loaded. Also, in last line add: `()` so it would be: `})();`